# Join 3 tables and return whatever is not in the 2nd and 3rd

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables (users, assignedtechnicians, assignedsupervisors)

[image]

technicianid and uspervisorid are foreign keys  to user id
stationid and regionid are foreign keys to some other tables

Essentialy users are assigned to posts that way 
what i want to do is output the users that are not assigned to a post, in this case:

[image]

I know that full outer join must be the way to go but i cant get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your query to be like this:

```
SELECT * from users U where U.user_id NOT IN (SELECT technicianid FROM assignedtechnicians) AND U.user_id NOT IN (SELECT uspervisorid FROM assignedsupervisors);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use two `not exists` conditions for this, one to search in each bridge table:

```
select u.*
from users
where
    not exists (select 1 from assignedtechnicians ast where ast.technicianid = u.id)
    and not exists (select 1 from assignedsupervisors ass where ass.supervisorid = u.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `LEFT JOIN` so that you can join on non-existing posts (the ones that you are looking for)

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.user_id = users.id
WHERE posts.id IS NULL
```

`posts.id IS NULL` means user does not have any posts.